# Creating Folders for Transformation - Acces Denied

Tags: java, saxon

I'm chaining a few xslt Transformations in a jar using saxon 9 ee as a library. 
In my char I wan't to create the ouput directory which I do like this:

```
int timestamp = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
File inputfolder = new File("input_ll_" + Math.abs(timestamp));
inputfolder.mkdir();
```

Then I tell Saxon to use that folder as output:

```
//output last transformation to file
transtemp.setDestination(getSerializer(inputfolder.toString()));
//start transformation
trans1.transform();
```

transtemp and trans one are both XsltTransformer Objects.

When I run my main method i get this:

> Exception in thread "main" net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\blabla\workspace\Tests\input_ll_1718557701 (Access Denied)

Any ideas ?

**Update:**

If i try to create a file there myself:

```
File check = new File(inputfolder.toString() + "/check.txt");
check.createNewFile();
```

it works, so it seems it's a problem with saxon ?

**Update 2:**

Yeah, classic me being stupid. I have to pass a path to a file not just to a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question. The File passed to getSerializer() must not be a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
inputfolder.setWritable(true)
```

Comment: sry, no luck with that. Still get the same error message and isWritable() actually returns true.

Comment: Exception is coming at this line `transtemp.setDestination(getSerializer(inputfolder.toString()));`?

Comment: no its it's thrown when i start the transformation so here `trans1.transform();`

Comment: And what is the method body of `transform`?

Comment: sry, I don't have the sources for that.

Comment: Have you checked if input_ll_1718557701 is created in folder Tests?

Comment: yes i did. it is created and i have access over the explorer.